# Как составить универсальное регулярное выражение для двух случаев?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть 2 одинаковые строки с кавычками и без кавычек:

```
url("../images/logo.png") left bottom no-repeat;
url(../images/logo.png) left bottom no-repeat;
```

Нужно вытащить адрес файла.

Если вытаскивать с кавычками, то использую `/url\(\K[^)]+/`, но оно также захватывает строки с url(data:...)

Как составить универсальное регулярное выражение, чтобы оно в обоих случаях доставало адрес файла без кавычек и игнорировало url(data:...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно это делать следующим регулярным выражением:

```
'/url\((?!data)['"]?\K[^)'"]+/'
```

https://regex101.com/r/cPxKup/3

Comment: у вас  url(data:...) пропускает

Comment: В функции preg_match_all выдает ошибку Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"]?\K[^)'"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: Туда вообще эта регулярка правильно не всает, хотя на примере все так, как нужно

Comment: Не заэкранировал кавычки, все ок

Answer (score 2):

Исключает data: из выборки, игнорирует кавычки в выборке

`/url\((?!['"]?data:)['"]?(.+)['"]?\)/`

https://regex101.com/r/kJEgaq/1

Comment: В функции preg_match_all выдает ошибку Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting ',' or ')'

Answer (score -1):

Смотреть вторую группу

```
/url\((["']?)(?!data:)([^'"].*?)\1\)/
```

```js
`url("../images/logo.png") left bottom no-repeat;
url(../images/logo.png) left bottom no-repeat;
Нужно вытащить адрес файла.
Если вытаскивать с кавычками, то использую /url\(\K[^)]+/,
но оно также захватывает строки с url(data:...)
url("data:...")
`.replace(/url\((["']?)(?!data:)([^'"].*?)\1\)/g, (m, q, url) => {
  console.log(m + "\n" + url)
})
```